# AmCharts DateAxis shows very wrong values

Tags: amcharts4

I have a chart with a DateAxis, a ValueAxis and two Series.
One Series contains all the data loaded in a certain timeperiod. For example if it is 18:00, all the data from 00:00 to 18:00 is in this series.
The other series is kind of a "placeholder" series. It contains two datapoints: 00:00 and 00:00 of the next day. I do this in order to get a white space on the right side of the chart, indicating that on a certain part of the period is loaded:
[image]
As you can see, this works fine. However, there is some major issue with this: as you can see, the last datapoint is some time before 18:00. The person using this graph would then conclude that the last datapoint was fetched at around 17:50 or so.

When zooming in however, this happens:

[image]

As you can see, the Datapoint is actually after 18:00.

I am pretty sure already why this happens: the vertical grid line on 18:00 is not actually indicating that it is 18:00 at this point of the grid, but more or less the middle of the 18th hour of the day. This would be fine by me, if it where not for that change that happens when zooming in a little bit.

I would prefer if the chart shows me the exact times if the granularity is less than days (basically, hours,minutes,seconds) and shows me "periods" when the granularity is higher than days (days,months,years)

Sadly, I do not know how to resolve this issue myself.

Comment: Have you checked the gridIntervals property?

Comment: A fiddle would really help on this one.